# Why does my ListView display only one row?

Tags: android, listview

I have custom adapter for ListView. No matter how many items are passed to it it displays only one row.

I verified by debugging that overrided methods return correct result.

For example

```
getCount()
```

> returns: 3

```
getView(2, null, (ListView)rootView)
```

> returns: expected view with TextView holding item name.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you post your `ListAdapter` class?

Comment: Can you add the item layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researching I found that my ListView was nested inside of ScrollView. Moving it outside of ScrollView solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your row's root view has android:layout_height="wrap_content". Might be that one row is as big as the whole screen. Try scrolling. If you see other rows this is the problem.

For a better response please post the adapter's code

Comment: Thanks for tip with trying to scolli! Items were not visible, but indeed they were scrolling which led me to solution of the problem. It was not the layout height but nesting ListVIew inside ScrollView.